# Total reputation value on that day

Tags: feature-request, reputation

In the reputation report log `?tab=reputation` at `post` tab, why there is not value for the total reputation value achieved till that day?

For example, could any member tell us what his/her reputation on `17-May-2016`?

The statistics only describes the change of reputation without any mention to the total reputation score gained till that date.

Comment: No, Could you able to tell me, for example, what did your total reputation on 17-May-2016? @yellowantphil

Comment: Try here - http://stackoverflow.com/reputation Mine was+71 to  42990  on 17th May 2016

Comment: Yes it is very cool, so, I think it should be easy to be added to the GUI. @Paulie_D